# Xcode 5 archive error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, architecture, archive

I am trying to use xcode 5 to archive an ios app so i can release it to the app store. I have the provisioning profiles and certificates to do so but when I go to archive my app, I receive the following error:
*Command/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang  failed with exit code 1*
When I pushed the drop down xcode gives me a lot of info about the error that mentions the archive and the architectures (armv7 for example) and the error ends with .pch
Does anyone know how to fix this? I looked at it on another form and that told me to delete armv7s so I did that and that deleted two errors but on remains. Any help would be grealy appreciated. This is my first app and I am an objective-c, xcode and ios beginner. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you included any libraries in your project? Can you copy the build log somewhere and link to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to fix this by setting "build active only architectures" to "no". I set architectures to "Standard Architectures". I downloaded a distribution provisioning profile from the ios developer center and then set all of the bundle id's and app id's to match each other. I made sure I had no missing files. I then archived the app (make sure the run option is set to "ios device") and added icons (must be .png) and validated it. I then distributed it to the app store. This avoids this problem and any other problem that you may encounter during the distribution process. I'm sincerly grateful for all of your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)" to your header search path, this will hopefully solve your issue.

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include  
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)  
$(inherited)                                                            These are the all of the header search paths I had but I still received the same error even after adding the one you requested. Is there something I should delete? Can you see any other problems? Thanks again

Comment: Kindly check these link may they helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371521/xcode-5-archive-build-fail-but-normal-build-successfully     http://www.juce.com/forum/topic/xcode-5-archive-builds-arrgh     http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/22275/xcode-build-and-archive-error-no-such-file-or-dire.html