# Integrate swift Google Protocol Buffers with Xcode swift project

Tags: swift3, protocol-buffers

I use the framework protobuf from https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf
in my xcode project in swift. Everything works fine for building for my iphone : I build the framework protobuf for my iphone and add the framework to my project.

But when I want to archive my project to Apple store, no way to make it working. Archive fails and errors are like library is not correct due to build for Generic IOS device ?

The documentation on apple/swift-protobuf it is explained :
Add the Protobuf target from the Xcode project in this package to your project.
How should it be done ? How to add a new target in the xcode ? add all the sources in the same project ? Thanks to anybody that can reply even just the last part of this question.

Answer (score 0):

found answer here :[xcode 5 archive build fail, but normal build successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371521/xcode-5-archive-build-fail-but-normal-build-successfully)

protobuf swift apple has to be build for the same architecture than the project.

"When you archive it builds all the architectures specified by the intersection of the Build Settings "Architectures and Valid Architectures"